# Session guard doesn't found

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, eloquent

I use laravel and I use mltiple auth for the connection.
My code in authentification

```
if (Auth::guard('patient')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
            //if(Auth::attempt($request->only($field, 'password'))){
                //put session
                Session::put('key', $user->id);
                //change le status en ligne
                Patient::WHERE('id', Auth::patient()->id)->UPDATE(['status' => 1]);
                //redirect url
                return redirect('/users/profile')->with('success', 'Bienvenue '.$user->firstname.', vous êtes bien connecté');
            }else{
                return redirect('/users/login')->with('error', 'Email or username incorrect!');
            }
```

In auth.php, I have

```
'guards' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'patient' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'patients',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
   ],
],
```

After execute, I found this error

BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::patient does not exist.

What is the wrong in my code?

Comment: Show provider section from auth.php

Comment: @Ts8060
[code]
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Users::class,
        ],

        'patients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Patient::class,
        ],
    ],

Comment: Is your Patient class extended Authenticatable class?

Comment: @Ts8060 this is true class

Comment: where you are trying to execute this guard code  ? in which section in controller or anywhere else ?

Comment: @C2486 in controller I execute auth code

Comment: please try this in web route file ?

Comment: @C2486 explain, I didn't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with your code is there is no method named `patient` on the `SessionGuard`.

`Auth::patient()` is `Auth::guard(null)->patient()`  ... there is no `patient` method defined on a guard, nor would there be.

`Auth::user()` is `Auth::guard(null)->user()` which means return the current authenticated user. `user` does not mean User model or any name defined in a config file. `user` is the concept of the current person/entity using the application. The USER who is using it.

Comment: I use this
Patient::WHERE('id', Auth::guard('patient')->user()->id)->UPDATE(['status' => 1]);
It's ready with code

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Auth::guard('patient')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        //if(Auth::attempt($request->only($field, 'password'))){
            //put session
            Session::put('key', $user->id);
            //change le status en ligne
            Patient::WHERE('id', Auth::guard('patient')->user()->id)->UPDATE(['status' => 1]);
            //redirect url
            return redirect('/users/profile')->with('success', 'Bienvenue '.$user->firstname.', vous êtes bien connecté');
        }else{
            return redirect('/users/login')->with('error', 'Email or username incorrect!');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if define your own login or signup and you got this kind of error
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard:: guard does not exist.
Then you should  import or use then session class  as define below
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
And your function should be defined as

```
public function postSingIn(Request $request)
{
   if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$request['email'],['password'=>$request['password']]]))
   {

      return redirect()->action('BackendController@deshboard');
   }
   return redirect()->back();
}
```